# Push data from excel to a word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to push excel data to a word document. The word document is a pre-existing document that needs to be filled in with values and a lot IDs. I have the word document set up so that all the spots that need data filled in from excel are Rich Content Controls. I inserted the Rich Content Control to each spot on the document that needs to be filled.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Excel Data

Only pasted 10 rows for sample data.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Word Document. Rich Content Controls in "Weight" Column and "Lot" Column

What I want to accomplish is to push the "weights" from the excel spreadsheet into the "weight" column on the word document and push the "bulk lot" from the excel spreadsheet into the "lot" column of the word document.

```
Sub PushDatatoWord()
  'Declare the appropriate variables
  Dim wordApp As Word.Application
  Dim wDoc As Word.Document
  Dim r As Integer

'Create a link to the microsoft word application
  Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.application")
'Create variable of the word document
Set wDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("Worddoc.docx")
wordApp.Visible = True
r = 2

For i = 1 To 20
    wDoc.ContentControls(i).Range.Text = Sheets("Boxes_Push").Cells(r, 3)
    r = r + 1
Next i

wordApp.Documents.Close
wordApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Above is the code that I have written, it pushes the values but it doesn't put them all into the correct column, the code is looping through all the content controls on the word document and placing the values in the next control. How do I separate the content controls on the word document so I can send the data to the appropriate column??

EDIT TO ORIGINAL POST:

[![Excel Worksheet with a range from B2,C15][3]][3]

[![Word Document with named content controls][4]][4]

```
'1. Name all content controls on word document. weight1, weight2, weight3, etc. lot1, lot2, lot3, etc.
'2. Create a 2d array with the values and lot . Read range values to arrary.
'3. Use SelectContentControlsByTitle() in a foreach loop with the array created.


Sub dataToWord()

    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Dim r As Long
    Dim arr As Variant
        
    'create connection to the word application
    
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.application")
    
    'Set the word document, content controls named weight1, weight2, etc and lot1, lot2, etc
    
    Set wDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\tyler.masson\Desktop\PushToWord\testpush_withnames.docx")
    wordApp.Visible = True
    r = 2
 
    'range created on worksheet from cells B2,C15 called "range"
    arr = Range("range").Value
    For Each i In arr
        wDoc.SelectContentControlsByTitle(Weight).Range.Text = Sheets("testpush").Cells(r, 2)
        r = r + 1
        
    Next i
    
   
    wordApp.Documents.Close
    wordApp.Quit


End Sub
```

I'm having trouble with the for each loop. I'm not entirely sure how to loop through each content control by title (weight and lot?) and then to assign the values in the created array to those content controls.

I really appreciate help on this.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb4e8.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsvaM.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyNuj.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6G0c.png

Comment: Do you need content controls, or can you just put the text directly in the cell?

Comment: First: prepare contentcontrols with given names in Word document e.g. weight1, weight2, weight 3 ect and the same for lot1, lot2... Second: read your range values to 2D array (name-value pair). Third: use SelectContentControlsByTitle() in a foreach loop with your array. PS please, don't use Integer type in 2020- use Long instead...

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any relationship between the Excel data and the Word data. The Lot #s in Excel are prefixed with PT, but the prefix is missing in Word and, moreover, the numbers there and in the Weight column are decimals, whereas in Excel they're integers. What's the deal?

Comment: @Rafał B.Thank you for your comment. I have tried to integrate the concepts you provided in my code below: I'm fairly new with VBA so I'm not sure if I am creating the array correctly or if I am doing the for each loop with the contentcontrolsbytitle(). I have assigned all the content controls in the word document to weight1, weight2, etc as well as lot1, lot2, etc. I added the new code to the bottom of my original post. Ill include new schreeen shots too. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TimWilliams We have had instances were people are inputting the wrong numbers! Very prone to human error. That is why I am trying to accomplish this task. The user only has to input the value of the weights once in the spreadsheet and it is transferred to the form.

Comment: @macropod . My bad - I posted some bad examples of pictures. The word document was an example with code I had already written showing that the values are transferred to the incorrect position. I have edited my post please check it out to see if you can help in any way I would really appreciate that!

Comment: I was asking why you don't prepare a blank Word table *without* content controls (which only seem to add a layer of complexity here) and use the VBA to populate the Word table cell directly.

Comment: @Tim Williams The form is sent from a third party. I cant create a blank word document because the word document is already created.

Comment: In your post you say you inserted the content controls.  I'm asking if there's a specific reason you did that.

Comment: @ Tim Williams I thought this was the only way to get data into word from excel. I'm fairly new with all this, is there another way to do it? I appreciate your help greatly.

Comment: @RafałB. Any chance you've had a look at my updated script? I can't seem to figure it out!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Sub dataToWord()

    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Dim wDoc As Word.document, tbl As Word.Table
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, maxRows As Long, i As Long
    Dim arr As Variant
        
'    Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.application")
'    Set wDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\tyler.masson\Desktop\PushToWord\testpush_withnames.docx")
'    wordApp.Visible = True
    
    'using an already-open doc for testing
    Set wordApp = GetObject(, "word.application")
    Set wDoc = wordApp.activeDocument
    
    Set tbl = wDoc.Tables(1) 'assuming just one table

    r = 2
    c = 2
    maxRows = 10 'how many rows in the first set of columns
                 '  before we need to move over to the next set?

    'maxRows = tbl.Rows.Count - 1 'dynamic count
    
    'range created on worksheet from cells B2,C15 called "range"
    arr = Range("range").Value
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        'put the values directly in the cells
        tbl.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = arr(i, 1)
        tbl.Cell(r, c + 2).Range.Text = arr(i, 2)
        
        'time to switch to next column?
        If i = maxRows Then
            c = c + 5
            r = 2
        Else
            r = r + 1
        End If
        
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @ Tim Williams Thank you so much! This worked perfectly. Let us say that there are 45 boxes (so 45 rows in excel document) and there are 25 spaces in the word document per column. Would I change the max rows = 25 or max rows = 45? And for transferring values to word documents would I change the if i = maxrows ? I appreciate your help so much. I am trying to get it to the point where the number of rows in the excel document can range between 1-60. Sometimes 4 boxes are sent out and sometimes 50 are sent out. Thanks again!

Comment: `maxRows` is how many rows you can fill out going down the left-hand side of the Word table, so half of the total number of slots in that table. `maxRows = 10` should be the only line you need to change.  Or you can make it dynamic by using `(tbl.Rows.Count-1)`  - the `-1` is to account for the header row.  See my edit above

Comment: Great, thank you so much! I will give that a try in my workbook project.

Comment: @ Tim Williams, if you have time could yuo check out my new questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62543255/vba-data-from-excel-to-word-document-using-contentcontrolsbytitle I am trying to push data now to already created labels - such a pain in my ass!!!

Comment: I need to expand my code! I now need to get the case boxes 51 - 100 on page 2 of the word document. Exact same format as page 1, how would I accomplish this? I tried looking up how to connect to the next page in word but to no avail. I tried setting Set tbl = wDoc.Tables(2) so that it includes 2 tables of the word document but am not sure how to push the data to those columns and rows on page 2. Appreciate any help greatly! Thanks again.